# Openstack/devstack virtual machine installation error

Tags: mysql, windows, openstack, devstack

I want to contribute to Openstack. Keeping this in mind, I git cloned devstack on virtual machine with Ubuntu 14:0 on Windows XP. After this, I ran ./stack.sh. It was not working. I was not able to launch an instance.I tried deleting the devstack and git cloned again. Even now its not working.

```
git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
```

I get the following error. I am using my computer as an administrator.

```
sudo mysql -uroot -pa2350bf7c5f41b70a808 -h127.0.0.1 -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '\''root'\''@'\''%'\'' identified by '\''a2350bf7c5f41b70a808'\'';'
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
+ exit_trap
+ local r=1
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ kill_spinner
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
```

What is the error and how to overcome the error? I m presuming that the error is due to permission settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove mysql and try running script again.

```
apt-get purge mysql-server
apt-get purge mysql*
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ /etc/mysql/
```

The problem is that devstack installs mysql and set a root password. If you run dev stack again without removing mysql, it won't install mysql again and keeps current installation. Since the  devstack script doesn't know old mysql password, the whole thing fails.

Comment: I am still running the stack.sh script.I will accept this as an answer when everything churns out fine. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try `apt-get purge mysql*`  and `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/` ,  `rm -rf /etc/mysql/` Then try installing devstack.

Comment: after I deleted, it is throwing up an error MYSQLDB not found.

Comment: install mysql and set root password as 'stackdb' and then try running it again.

Comment: You may also want to checkout a specific git branch (git checkout stable/icehouse) as the master branch is the latest code and can have issues.

Comment: @Harikrishnan, I am not sure how to set root password? CAn you exactly give the steps to do the same. I m not sure how to choose

Comment: `mysqladmin -u root password stackdb`

Comment: @Harikrishnan, I am still getting the same error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password yes)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem when trying to re-install devstack on a VM and was happy to find the answer posted above by [Harikrishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1740715/harikrishnan).

**I ran into another issue after following his solution:** 
The `/var/lib/mysql` directory is provided by the `'mariadb-server'` package.  Removing this directory manually and leaving the mariadb-server package installed results in an error when trying to run stack.sh.  Removing both mysql-server and the mariadb-server packages solved the problem for me.

```
apt-get purge mysql-server mariadb-server
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ /etc/mysql/
/opt/stack/stack.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

For encountering this problem follow these steps:

1. sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2. mysql -u root mysql
3. UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('a2350bf7c5f41b70a808') WHERE User='root';
4. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
5. exit;
6. sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
7. Now do mysql -u root -p and enter the password mentioned in step 3.

Comment: The password I have mentioned in step 3 is from your log only, therefore you can use it with no issues.

Comment: While installing devstack on Ubuntu change the Ip to static also.